# How to calculate $\int \frac{x}{\sqrt x -2}dx$

Tags: integration

I don't know how to solve the following integral. I need some suggestions. Thank you!

$$ \int \frac{x}{\sqrt x -2}dx$$

Comment: Try the cov $x=t^2$.

Comment: cov=change of variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\int \frac{x }{\sqrt x -2}dx$$
$x=t^2 \ , \ dx=2t \ dt$
$$\int\frac{2t^3 }{t-2}dt=2\int\frac{t^3-8}{t-2}dt+16\int\frac{dt}{t-2}=$$
$$=2\int\frac{(t-2)(t^2+2t+4)}{t-2}dt+16\int\frac{dt}{t-2}=$$
$$=2\int(t^2+2t+4)dt+16\int\frac{dt}{t-2}=$$

Answer (score 3):

Let $t=\sqrt x$ so $x=t^2$ and $dx=2tdt$ hence

$$\displaystyle \int \frac{xdx}{\sqrt x -2}dx=2\int\frac{t^3}{t-2}dt$$
Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 2):

Setting $t=\sqrt{x}$ one gets
\begin{eqnarray}
\int\frac{x}{\sqrt{x}-2}\,dx&=&2\int\frac{t^3}{t-2}\,dt=2\int\frac{8+t^3-8}{t-2}\,dt\\
&=&2\int\left(\frac{16}{t-2}+t^2+2t+4\right)\,dt\\
&=&32\ln|t-2|+\frac23t^3+2t^2+8t+C\\
&=&32\ln|\sqrt{x}-2|+\frac23x\sqrt{x}+2x+8\sqrt{x}+C
\end{eqnarray}